# fixing mis-encoded Chinese in file names

Tags: encoding, unicode, chinese

I'm saddled with a bunch of files whose names are garbled beyond recognition. Even though I more or less know what those names originally contained, fixing them by hand would involve a lot of hassle, so I'm looking for a way to do that automatically.

What could possibly have happened for these Chinese characters to become this way:

```
### original => garbled
### UTF-8       UTF-8
### UCS-2       UCS-2

雨中                 => ╙ъ╓╨
e9 9b a8 e4 b8 ad       e2 95 99 d1 8a e2 95 93 e2 95 a8
96e8 4e2d               2559 044a 2553 2568

照片                 => ╒╒╞м
e7 85 a7 e7 89 87       e2 95 92 e2 95 92 e2 95 9e d0 bc
7167 7247               2552 2552 255e 043c

女人                 => ┼о╚╦
e5 a5 b3 e4 ba ba       e2 94 bc d0 be e2 95 9a e2 95 a6
5973 4eba               253c 043e 255a 2566

童心                 => ═п╨─
e7 ab a5 e5 bf 83       e2 95 90 d0 bf e2 95 a8 e2 94 80
7ae5 5fc3               2550 043f 2568 2500

绿肥红瘦             => ┬╠╖╩║ь╩▌
e7 bb bf e8 82 a5 e7 ba a2 e7 98 a6    e2 94 ac e2 95 a0 e2 95 96 e2 95 a9 e2 95 91 d1 8c e2 95 a9 e2 96 8c
7eff 80a5 7ea2 7626     252c 2560 2556 2569 2551 044c 2569 258c
```

I've seen similar things happen before, for example when a UTF-8-encoded sequence gets erroneously interpreted as single-byte (e.g. Latin-1 or CP1251) and then converted to UTF-8 once again, but that does not seem to be the case here.

There is actually no guarantee that the original encoding was UTF-8, it could have been GB or some other legacy encoding used in China.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`╙ъ╓╨` is `d3 ea d6 d0` in IBM codepage 866, which is also `雨中` in the GB2312, GBK and CP936 codepages. So it's most likely a fairly normal codepage mis-detection (of GB2312 text as IBM866).

```
echo e2 95 99 d1 8a e2 95 93 e2 95 a8 | unhex | iconv -t cp866 | iconv -f gb2312
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you so much!

Comment: For what it's worth, my initial guess is "it's mis-detected as some IBM codepage" due to the presence of 'box-drawing' characters like ╙, so I tried converting from UTF-8 to all of the codepages from iconv -l | grep ^CP.../, to find the ones that didn't fail conversion (had all necessary characters such as ъ), of which there were just two and cp866 was the more plausible looking one (giving exactly 4 characters). At the same time, tried converting the original from UTF-8 to a few candidate charsets such as GB2312. Both attempts "met in the middle" with d3 ea d6 d0 as the output.

Comment: Haha, the peculiar "boxiness" of those characters did put me in mind of CP866 (which I'm very familiar with since it was the default Russian encoding back in the DOS days), so I did half-heartedly try out a few UTF/CP866 combinations, but I would never have thought of trying that codepage in conjunction with GB2312.

Answer (score 6):

A common cause for such errors is zip/unzip across cultures,
although I cannot assert that this happened in your case.

The examples that you gave seem somewhat similar to the one described
in the article
[Corrupted Chinese File Name with Un-ZIP](https://www.herongyang.com/PHP-Chinese/Conversion-Corrupted-Chinese-File-Name-Un-ZIP.html)
on line 3:

[image]

Some more cases are shown in the article
[Zip files and Encoding – I hate you](https://marcosc.com/2008/12/zip-files-and-encoding-i-hate-you/),
where another example is given of three different encodings for one
character, depending on where this character was zipped:

| File name | Zip in Windows | Zip in Linux | Zip in Mac OS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ñ | a4 (Extended US-ASCII/CP437) | C3 B1 (UTF-8 NFC) | 6E CC 83 (UTF-8 NFD) |

For Chinese, there are more encodings possible with older methods of
encoding.

If you're looking for an automatic method to undo the garbled names,
then without knowing the original encoding and the utilities and
operating systems that were involved, I wouldn't know where to even begin.

If they are similar to line 3 above, you could start by zipping up
in Linux and unzipping in Windows GB18030, or similar tries in
order to do these zip/unzip actions in reverse.

Comment: You are the hero!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `convmv` utility which can convert file names from one character set to another. Something like `convmv -t cp866 -f gb2312 * ../target` - validate what it does and then invoke with `--notest`.

Comment: Or you could just use `for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | iconv -t cp866 | iconv -f gb2312)"; done` (do a dry run with an `echo` instead of `mv` to make sure everything is OK).